# Assistance with having a div stay in position multiple resolutions

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and i am having a programming issue with a floating div.

I am trying it to stay the same width no matter the resolution.

I made a fiddle with my code.

What did i do wrong?

Btw it is being used in a bootstrap theme I purchased.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dvmad/960a15nm/2/

```
<div class="container rotatingimagetextpadding">
  <div class="rotatingimagetextholder">
    <img src="assets/images/genericassets/slider_img_1.png" alt="lincoln" />
    <span class="rotatingimagetext" >Verbiage</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have different padding values for different media queries. Change them, Have a constant one.

Answer (score 0):

Take away the padding percentages and set absolute dimensions using px instead in your @media. The percentages is what is changing the size when you shrink the screen.